# C programming(scanf advanced).....for expert C programmers

Tags: c

I'm trying to introduce this in devC++ and Microsoft Visual Studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char* filename;
    scanf(" %a[^\n]%*c",&filename);
    printf("\n%s",filename);
    free(filename);
    system("pause");
    return(0);

}
```

When I try to compile the code, I get a console where I introduce the string with spaces inside the string but, after that, while the program are printing the string, I get a rigmarole.

Several years ago, I used to use this format specifier to introduce strings with several whithspaces and now I have this problem. What is this?. I have to use C, nothing about using other languages neither other functions(like fgets).

Comment: `free(filename);`?? You have not allocated any memory for `filename`, so `scanf()` will fail and so will `free()`

Comment: @PaulR This code uses gcc's extension, `%a` allocates the string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: thanks for the clarification - that's a new one on me...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight isn't `%a` obsolete, replaced by `%m`?

Comment: Did you read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) ?

Comment: That is what I am looking at.

Comment: "*When I try to compile the code, I get a console where I introduce the string with spaces inside the string but, after that, while the program are printing the string, I get a rigmarole.*" -- I'm afraid I have no idea what this means. Are you describing the behavior when you run the program? What is a "rigmarole"? Please show us what your program prints rather than describing it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell that I've used the %m alternative but I had the same problem with the output. I print the output coming up next(below his response.....wait a minute), but maybe be a problem with using of Windows, as dasblinkenlight says. Sorry for my english level, I'm spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code an assignment-allocation modifier, which is a GNU extension. It is not available in Microsoft Visual Studio.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to make it work with strings of unlimited length. If the length can be limited to some fixed number, pre-allocate your memory buffer, and specify the limit in your format string. You could also pre-allocate your buffer on the automatic storage, like this:

```
char filename[261];
scanf(" %260[^\n]%*c", filename);
printf("\n%s",filename);
```

Note that `filename` has an extra `char` for null termination.

Comment: This is the solution, but some questions.....what do you want to say me about pre-allocating your buffer on the automatic storage??? I understand what you are saying, i'm able to use either malloc or brackets and define the size inside them.....but what another alternative I have??.

Comment: I suppose that it's also possible to do this:                                                                char filename[261];
scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", filename);
printf("\n%s",filename);.............instead of pre-allocating in both of them

Comment: @user2205174 "brackets" syntax means allocating `filename` "on the stack". The official name for "the stack" is "automatic memory". `malloc` allocates memory from the "heap", which is a nickname for "dynamic memory".

Comment: I suppose that it's also possible to do this: char filename[261]; scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", filename); printf("\n%s",filename);.............instead of pre-allocating in both of them

Comment: @user2205174 `260` after `%` is not allocation, it's the limit. Without this limit a user would be able to cause buffer overruns simply by typing more than 260 characters.

Comment: Ok, the problem is solved, thank you for all. Although, if neccesary to use Microsoft Visual Studio with assignment-allocation modifier.....would you know the way to proceed.....modifying the code of internal libraries???

Comment: @user2205174 You are welcome. If you are no longer looking for help with this question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check  mark next to it. This would let others know that your problem is solved, and earn you a badge on stack overflow.

Comment: Although, if neccesary to use Microsoft Visual Studio with assignment-allocation modifier.....would you know the way to proceed.....modifying the code of internal libraries???

Comment: @user2205174 assignment-allocation modifier is specific to GNU. One could try to port that library and make it work with VS, but it is hardly the most "economical" approach to reading a string of unlimited length.

Answer (score 0):

Allocate memory for the pointer before writing to it.Then scan the string

```
char *filename = malloc(100);
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", filename);
```

Comment: OP's code uses gcc's `%a` extension, which allocates memory for OP.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight oh !! I didn't knew.. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: It is not a `gcc` extension, it might be a `glibc` one.

Comment: you are good at C Basile :).........I didn't know that.

Comment: yes, it's a nonstandard extension of glibc 2.0. and, therefore, GNU(gcc compiler). You can allocate a buffer without being needed to use malloc. But this specifier supossed a confusion with the other specifier format used in the float pointer(%f) and, because of this, POSIX 2008 introduced the %m specifier format.